# Allow members of my website upload videos to YOUTUBE through my account

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

1. I register account in Youtube.
2. People, who is logged in in my website can upload their videos on my site.
3. Videos is uploaded to my Youtube account.
4. So, one account of youtube holds all uploaded videos by my website's members

Is it possible to do that? If you didn't understand, feel free to ask.

+I want to be able to allow people add their name of video, add tags and so on.

Comment: How can it be not a programming issue? So then what?

Comment: If I ( my users ) upload for example 5 thousands videos, do I infringe any of youtube's terms?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this question as well. It seems with deprecation of the Youtube v2 api this is no as easy as it was. If anyone can post an example of how this is done using OAuth2, etc, that would be epic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the YouTube API, you can implement that. Have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/youtube/overview.html):

Comment: This now resides at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos

Comment: Steffen, have you set up Youtube uploading with the v3 api?